# Error code 135, Error message Could not fingd update-config.json. Run webdriver-manager update to download the binaries

Tags: node.js, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to execute my tests in nodejs using protractor.

Example `protractor protractor.conf`
When I run protractor protractor.conf, I get error  Error code 135, Error message Could not fingd update-config.json. Run webdriver-manager update to download the binaries

I ran the following command but still get the above error message

```
webdriver-manager update -- proxy http://
```

protractor.conf.js

```
/*global jasmine */
var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');
var TfsReporter = require('jasmine-tfs-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './src/tests/*spec.js'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    /*'browserName': 'phantomjs',
    'phantomjs.binary.path': require('phantomjs-prebuilt').path,
    'phantomjs.ghostdriver.cli.args': ['--loglevel=DEBUG']*/
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  useAllAngular2AppRoots: false,
  beforeLaunch: function() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: '../PartyAndIndustryDataMigration'
    });
  },
  onPrepare: function() {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter());
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new TfsReporter());
  }
};
```

Comment: Did you got solution for this issue, because I'm also facing this issue for the past 1 week and searching for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure (and cannot it check now), but shouldn't command look like that:

`webdriver-manager update --proxy http://` (without space between `--` and `proxy`)?

Comment: It just a typo from my myside in the post. The command executes and installs the webdriver updates but i still get the above error message when i run protractor protractor.conf

Answer (score 0):

I guess `chrome driver & update-config.json` couldn't downloaded at the time of `webdriver-manager update`.

> Just for verification go to
>   node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\
>   location and look if everything downloaded properly?

If there is problem on downloading `chrome driver` you can check `chrome-response.xml` in same location for reason. One reason could be chrome driver website is in blacklisted or behind the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

1.Open Command prompt or terminal.

2.Go to your project root directory.

3.Enter the below command and hit Enter key.

`node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update`

This command will update the WebDriver Manager.